# React Native Dropdown Text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I'm trying to change todoInput2 which defined in different class. This dropdown selection done in different place. I couldn't change todoInput2 as selected label in dropdown. Before dropdown selection I had an text input bar. Similar style didn't work on this.

```
  const InputBar2: FC = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(undefined);
  const data = [
    { label: 'Resident'},
    { label: 'Visitor'},
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.inputinstruction}>{ 'Class:' }</Text>
      
      <DropMenu label="Select" data={data}  onSelect={setSelected}
        onChangeText={(todoInput2) => props.textChange({todoInput2})} 
        value={todoInput2}
        /> 

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton} onPress={props.addNewTodo}>
        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>ADD</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I call InputBar2 in the below code. Maybe I should change something in this place too. I didn't define textChange method. It is like onChangeText method already defined.

```
    <InputBar2
      addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
      textChange={(todoInput2) => this.setState({ todoInput2})}
      todoInput2={this.state.todoInput2}
    />
```

Full code provided in the below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../Header';
import InputBar from './InputBar1';
import InputBar2 from './InputBar2';
import TodoItem from './Item';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

    export default class Database extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          todoInput: '',
          todoInput2: '',
          todos: [
            { id: 0, title: 'Furkan Sarikaya', pos:'Resident',  done: false },
            { id: 1, title: 'Taha Tolga Saadet', pos:'Resident', done: false }
    
          ]
        }
      }
    
      addNewTodo () {
        let todos = this.state.todos;
    
        todos.unshift({
          id: todos.length,
          title: this.state.todoInput,
          pos: this.state.todoInput2,
          done: false
        });
    
        this.setState({
          todos: todos,
          todoInput: '',
          todoInput2: '',
        });
      }
    
      toggleDone (item) {
        let todos = this.state.todos;
    
        todos = todos.map((todo) => {
          if (todo.id == item.id) {
            todo.done = !todo.done;
          }
    
          return todo;
        })
    
        this.setState({todos});
      }
    
      setPos (item) {
          pos:item;
      }
    
      removeTodo (item) {
        let todos = this.state.todos;
    
        todos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== item.id);
    
        this.setState({todos});
      }
    
      render() {
        const statusbar = (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? <View style={styles.statusbar}></View> : <View></View>;
    
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {statusbar}
    
            <Header title="Database" />
    
            <InputBar
              addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
              textChange={(todoInput) => this.setState({ todoInput})}
              todoInput={this.state.todoInput}
            />
    
            <InputBar2
              addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
              textChange={(todoInput2) => this.setState({ todoInput2})}
              todoInput2={this.state.todoInput2}
            />
    
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.todos}
              extraData={this.state}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                return (
                  <TodoItem todoItem={item} toggleDone={() => this.toggleDone(item)} removeTodo={() => this.removeTodo(item)} />
                )
              }}
            />
    
    
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
      statusbar: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFCE00',
        height: 20,
      },
    })
```

Comment: change the variable name in onChangeText from todoInput2 to something else. Also the value field in DropMenu is showing todoInput2 which doesn't appear to be declared. Change it to props.todoInput2

Comment: I tried to change the variable name to selected.label or label or data but they didn't work. I'm pretty new at this stuff. I couldn't find a way to solve this.

Comment: <DropMenu label="Select" data={data}  onSelect={setSelected}
        onChangeText={(label) => {console.log(label); props.textChange(label);}} 
        value={props.todoInput2}
        />
Try this. if it doesn't work then does console show correct label value?

Comment: <InputBar2
          addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
          textChange={(todoInput2) => this.setState({ todoInput2})}
          todoInput2={this.state.todoInput2}
        />

Thank you for attention. It didn't work, console show correct label value but I call InputBar2 in the above code. Maybe I should change something in this place too.

Comment: Where is your textChange method defined? Please make changes in your original post

Comment: I updated the original post.

Comment: <InputBar2
      addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
      textChange={(todoInput2) => {console.log(todoInput2);this.setState({ todoInput2})}}
      todoInput2={this.state.todoInput2}
    />

What does the console show in this case. Is the value being passed correctly here?

Comment: if not, onChangeText={(todoInput2) => props.textChange(todoInput2)}  try it like this on drop menu. remove the {} parenthesis from todoInput2

Comment: It both didn't work, thank you for your attention.